# Quebra de linha no PHP com CSV

Tags: php, csv

Olá, amigos!

Tenho este CSV :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E este código em PHP:

```
<?php
// Create a table from a csv file 
$area = 0;
echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">\n\n";
$f = fopen("horarios_modificados.csv", "r", ";");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if($area == 0) echo "<thead>\n";
    if($area == 1) echo "<tbody>\n";
    $row = $line[0];    // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)
    $cells = explode(";",$row);
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    if($area == 0) echo "</thead>\n";
    $area++;
}
fclose($f);
echo "</tbody>\n";
echo "\n</table>\n";
?>
```

Gostaria que o ponto de exclamação "!" (já inserido no meu CSV) fosse um código no PHP para dar nova linha (quebra de linha) no CSV quando estiver em php no browser.

Pois atualmente fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando rapidamente, acho que isto bastaria:

```
echo "<td>" . str_replace("!", "<br>", htmlspecialchars($cell)) . "</td>\n";
```

Comment: Funcionou! Ja testei